# Creating a View within a CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-cardview

I want to create a `View` within a `CardView`. All it would be is a grey view that covers part of the `CardView`. If you see inside the card view on this image, you can see this grey view that is right in between the person's photo and right under his or her name here shown here:

[image]

I have tried to mimic this as shown below but I am a little confused. I have tried to add a `View` that is grey but for one thing, `View` will not extend to the entire `CardView` due to the fact that I have a `android:layout_margin="16dp"` declared for the nested `RelativeLayout` within the `CardView`. Secondly, I would prefer not to hard code the height of the `CardView`, but when try to put something like `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, the `View` doesn't even show. If anyone could point me in the right direction on how I can accomplish the grey `View` right under neath the person's name within the `CardView` that'd be great. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/material_color_grey_200"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv_news_feed"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/txt_post_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingRight="80dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/txt_timestamp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="@color/material_color_grey_400"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@id/txt_post_title"
                android:id="@+id/txt_statusMsg"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/poster_profile_photo"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/txt_statusMsg"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@id/txt_statusMsg"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_profile_photo"
                android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/material_color_grey_200"
                android:layout_below="@id/txt_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/privacy_status"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_name"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/num_comments" />

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_one"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
                />

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_two"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
                />

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_three"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
                />

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_four"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. Change the colors back i replaced them. The parent is wrap_content, but the footer height must be hard coded, or either the elements size in it, with margins top for the images. Also i used the images in the bottom that you already defined. The text is on the right not the left of the images

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_post_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingRight="80dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_timestamp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="#99000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_statusMsg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txt_post_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="88dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/poster_profile_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/poster_profile_photo"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:maxWidth="125dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/txt_name"
                android:background="#33000000"/>

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@id/poster_profile_photo"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/privacy_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_name"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txt_name"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/num_comments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                fresco:text="asdasd"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_one"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/num_comments"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                />

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_two"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/num_comments"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                />

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_three"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/num_comments"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                />

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_four"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/num_comments"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
                fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                fresco:roundingBorderWidth="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hey this is awesome! thanks for this! I just have one question: the `View` is covering my `SimpleDraweeView`. Is there any way I can make the `photo` appear over my `SimpleDraweeView`?

Comment: You mean the `SimpleDraweeView` on the left? Yeah just put it under the `View` in your layout. I made an edit you can check the change